# Blazor static file 404 errors on IIS / Server 2019 but not IIS Express / Win10

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor-server-side

The basic issue is that a .NET Core 3.1 Blazor server-side app, which works fine on a Win10 desktop under IIS Express, fails to serve static content referenced in _Host.cshtml when moved to Server 2019 running in-process under IIS (running in debug under VS2019, not published / deployed). Routine static content like CSS or JS files results in an HTTP 404 not-found error. The Blazor app itself runs fine and the client browser (still running from my desktop) is able to read embedded content such as the JS file to establish the websocket connection.

It seems to be a security issue. I realize that in theory static content is served anonymously. But two static files requested from an auth-protected Blazor page (one image file and one CSS file) *do* serve correctly. However, the IIS Express version that is working normally is configured with anonymous auth disabled and Windows auth enabled. I believe I have IIS configured the same way (below).

Details:

This is a somewhat complex Blazor server-side app which was originally developed over several months on my local workstation. Then it was shelved for a few months while we argued over whether to use Blazor. Company policy is to use dedicated server VMs as dev environments, so I pulled it down to the server from a git repo, but apart from tweaking some paths and switching to IIS, the code is the same. Two possibly-related factors are that it's an enterprise app so it involves Windows identity (LAN ID and AD groups) and anonymous access should not be permitted.

The default IIS site and all default app pools have been removed. There is one site pointed to an empty directory which is home to the bindings (ports 80 and 443 for both localhost and the machine's FQDN). The web app's app pool follows all the normal rules -- no managed CLR, AppPoolIdentity, etc. The Site Authentication and the web app Authentication has Windows auth enabled and anonymous disabled. The Site itself also has a dedicated unmanaged app pool. I'm aware of how AppPoolIdentity works, and the csproj folder does have the correct permissions for the correct virtual account, and these are inherited into wwwroot and so on.

As a test, on the server I created a new Blazor template app with SSL (but no ASP.NET Identity, which we never use), then I set up a new web app and pool in IIS the same way and it works fine. Of course, that has no auth, which again tells me it's a security issue, but I can't find anything else to tweak.

Comment: check the iis log or run failed request tracing that is it 404 error or 401. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis. if possible please provide more error detail.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal thanks, I'd forgotten all about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jalpa Panchal's suggestion to run failed request tracing, I realized IIS was attempting to serve the files from the parent site (the empty directory with the IP and port bindings) rather than the virtual web app.

As noted in the question, these were files referenced in `_Host.cshtml` and this was quickly and easily fixed by prefixing the `href` and `src` tags with a tilde.